# CSS Wildcard for Label

Tags: css, wildcard

I'm using the free NinjaForms plugin on my WP site. The free version doesn't provide formatting capability so I do it through CSS. By default, the labels are bold and I want them to be lighter. Below is the CSS I am using today.

```
#nf-field-1-wrap label, #nf-field-2-wrap label, #nf-field-3-wrap label, #nf-field-4-wrap label, #nf-field-5-wrap label, #nf-field-6-wrap label, {
    font-weight: 300;
}
```

It works...however, does not allow for future forms to be added without updating the CSS.

I'd like to be able to use a wildcard with the CSS style so all future fields automatically get the lighter font styling.

I tried this but it doesn't work.

```
label[id="nf-field- "] {
    font-weight: 300;
}
```

Also I checked the forum and found a post that addresses wildcards for labels and applied the format, but it doesn't work either.

```
label[id$="nf-field- "] {
    font-weight: 300;
}
```

url to the form: https://www.makingwavesweb.com/project-application/

HTML Example for 1 field: *updated html code

```
<div id="nf-field-24-wrap" class="field-wrap textbox-wrap nf-fail nf-error" data-field-id="24">

    <div class="nf-field-label">
        <label for="nf-field-24" class="">Company Name <span class="ninja-forms-req-symbol">*</span> </label>
    </div>

    <div class="nf-field-element">
        <input value="" class="ninja-forms-field nf-element" id="nf-field-24" name="nf-field-24" aria-invalid="true" aria-describedby="nf-error-24" type="text">
    </div>


</div>
```

Comment: Try `label[id^="nf-field-"]`

Comment: use classes? then use `.label-class {/*css*/}`

Comment: @BalázsVarga If you have an answer, please post it as an answer, not a comment.

Comment: @BalázsVarga Didn't work.

Comment: @TPop Please include the HTML of what you are trying to apply CSS to.

Comment: @TylerH Added HTML sample to question. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The wildcard to select `id`s that begin with a certain string is `^`.

So for that part, you would use `[id^="nf-field-"]`. If the label elements you want to style are *descendants* of the element with that ID, you would select them this way:

```css
[id^="nf-field-"] label { /* styles here */ }
```

Your attempt of `label[id$="nf-field-"]` would select `<label>` elements that have an ID *themselves* that *ends* in "nf-field-", but you have elements with the "nf-field" ID, and the labels you want to style are descendants of them. Further, your labels are descendants of the elements with the aforementioned "nf-field" IDs. Those two reasons are why your attempt(s) didn't work.

See the full list of attribute selectors at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors).

Comment: Thank makes sense but it's still not working.  For some reason that I don't understand, I have to target the id "nf-field-1-wrap" because id "nf-field-1" doesn't work.   So, using your suggested format I tried [id^="nf-field- -wrap "] label  but unfortunately still doesn't work.

Comment: Also updated the html in my question to reflect where the nf-field-1-wrap tag comes into play.

Comment: @TPop See this JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gdyhabjx/ Can you add some extra HTML (as you said you have multiple divs with a label in them, right?) to show how it isn't working for you?

Comment: NinjaForms lets me add a class to the container or element. While I was stumbling around I tried this code and it worked:    
           
  .nf-field-label label{
 font-weight: 300!important;
}

I'm not crazy about using !important but sometimes it's ok. right?

Comment: @TPop Sometimes !important is necessary, especially if you are dealing with multiple layers of abstraction in your environment. As long as you use it sparingly, it shouldn't cause a problem.